# Does PME activation differ between potato varieties?

Tags: food-science, potatoes

Potatoes contain the enzyme pectin-methyl esterase (PME). Par-boiling potatoes  at a temperature range between 130F to 140F, activates this enzyme, gelatinising the starch cells in the potato.

According to Dave Arnold's experiments on [Cooking Issues](http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/04/27/the-quest-for-french-fry-supremacy-part-1/index.html), this results in french fries that stay stiffer after frying. In my own testings, I have found that par-boiling potatoes at 140F before cooking them creates fluffier mashed potatoes as well.

Experiments on this enzyme that I have found online seem to test them on french fries, but they don't mention what variety of potatoes they use; high starch, waxy, low-moisture, high-moisture.

- High-starch, and low-moisture: Russets, Idahos, Yukon Golds
- Waxy and high-moisture: Granolas, Fingerlings, Desirees

My question is, **does the temperature range and effects of PME activation differ between varieties of potatoes?**

Comment: "Boiling" would be an inaccurate term for cooking in 130-140°F water, unless its being done at 35-39,000 feet above sea level, or in a partial vacuum.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yep, I have edited the description.